# Django different model manager on foreign key

Tags: django, django-models, django-database

I have model User. There are two managers, UserManager that filters query set by is_active, and AllUserManager.
Default manager is set to be UserManager.

User has foreign key to another model, named Address, having related_name='users'.

Problem is next. When User is_active is False, Address does not display inactive User in users collection.

Is it possible somehow to set AllUserManager to be default manager on the fly for some FK? I want to be able to list all users in address, regardless of their activity.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can [specify which manager to use](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#using-a-custom-reverse-manager) in queries. If `all_users = AllUserManager()` then:

```
# address is instance of Address
address.users(manager='all_users').all()
```

Also, if `all_users` is default manager, you can [set `use_for_related_fields = True`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/managers/#controlling-automatic-manager-types) on `AllUserManager`.

Comment: use_for_related_fields is deprecated, see: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.10/#manager-use-for-related-fields-and-inheritance-changes

Comment: But what about when its not a queryset but just an instance. eg: `phone.user` and the phone belongs to a user which is not included in the default manager for the related fields?